# background css image does not show up in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I have this image that shows up in every browser except for Internet Explorer 11<

How do I fix this? Here is the code.

```
.cartelement{position: relative;float: right;background: url(../images/cart.jpg) center center no-repeat#6B1682;font-size: 0px;width: 55px;}
.cartelement.mobile{ position: absolute; right:0; top: 0; background: url(../images/cart.jpg) center center no-repeat#6B1682; font-size: 0px; width: 55px;  padding-top:10px; }
.cartelement a{ color: #fff; font-size: 0px !important; height: 54px; width: 55px; float: left;}    
.cartelement a:hover{color: #fff !important;}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: try use background-image

Comment: I don't get any errors and I tried background-image as well but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try use `background: url("http://websitename.com/images/cart.jpg")` **IF IT'S ON THE WEB**

### Or on your **PC** 
 `background:url("C:\Users\Username\Filelocation\cart.jpg")`

Best Solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding quotation marks:

```
 background: url("../images/cart.jpg")
```